# OpenCart is deleting all decimals in admin panel

Tags: decimal, opencart

When I'm changing some product parameters in OpenCart admin panel and saving data, OpenCart deletes all decimals. Problem lies in admin panel not with displaying numbers on main shop page. It doesn't matter if I want to set price, weight ect. Decimals are always gone.
I was trying to find problem in OpenCart code but I can't. I didn't set that shop, I'm just helping friend with this problem.
I also checked database. Price, weight ect fields are set to decimal(15,4) so it's ok. When I'm updating data manually directly from database, everything is ok. I have no idea what to do.
Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find what you want on this file as a example `system/library/weight.php`
and the code what you have to change is this:

```
return number_format($value, 2, $decimal_point, $thousand_point) . $this->weights[$weight_class_id]['unit'];
```